setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion in Makefile (Microsoft Windows)
src/Makefile
SHELL := cmd.exe

target:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set foo=hello
    echo !foo! %foo%

run the target
cd src
mingw32-make.exe
// output: !foo!

Why setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion not work in Makefile ?
mingw32-make.exe --version
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-mingw32


Each action in a recipe is executed in separate shell. It means, that your recipe is equivalent of a shell script:
cmd.exe /c setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cmd.exe /c set foo=hello
cmd.exe /c echo !foo! %foo%

There are two ways to execute a recipe in one shell invocation.
First, is you can either write a multi line:
target:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion \
    set foo=hello                   \
    echo !foo! %foo%

Another way to do recipe in one shell is to use a special target .ONESHELL
Then your makefile can be
.ONESHELL:
target:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set foo=hello
    echo !foo! %foo%

Both approaches have limitations and caveats described in documentation. Choose what approach is better for you and your case.

I expect both solutions to fail, because setlocal doesn't work in a command line context. And getting multi-line batch commands to work within a command-line context is horribly complex.

.ONESHELL supports by new version of make.  And multi lines should be separated by &

As @White Owl said, it's a problem of separate shell invocations for each line.
This could be solved by using a batch file instead of single lines.
SHELL := cmd.exe

target:
    myTarget.bat

And myTarget.bat:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set foo=hello
echo !foo! %foo%

